# Pandas: remove rows of dataframe with unique index value

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove the rows of my dataframe (df) which have unique value as index. This is my df:

```
    A       B
1   3.803   4.797
1   3.276   3.878
2   5.181   6.342
3   6.948   9.186
3   8.762  10.136
4  10.672  12.257
4   8.266  13.252
5  13.032  14.656
6  15.021  17.681
6  16.426  15.07
```

I would like to remove the rows with index=2,5 to get a new dataframe (df_new) as follow:

```
    A       B
1   3.803   4.797
1   3.276   3.878
3   6.948   9.186
3   8.762  10.136
4  10.672  12.257
4   8.266  13.252
6  15.021  17.681
6  16.426  15.07
```

Is there some handy function in pandas to do that?
Thank you

Comment: Aside: while your question is perfectly reasonable, having duplicate indices causes enough headaches in practice that it should generally be avoided except as an intermediate step.

Comment: I completly agree. Hovewer, in my case the indexes indicate replicate measurements and that's the only way I see to refer to replicates...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `get_duplicates`:

```
In [36]:
df.loc[df.index.get_duplicates()]

Out[36]:
        A       B
1   3.803   4.797
1   3.276   3.878
3   6.948   9.186
3   8.762  10.136
4  10.672  12.257
4   8.266  13.252
6  15.021  17.681
6  16.426  15.070
```

`get_duplicates` returns an array of the duplicated indices:

```
In [37]:
df.index.get_duplicates()

Out[37]:
[1, 3, 4, 6]
```